# Using jQuery with apex:tabPanel

Tags: visualforce, force.com, jquery, tab

I am using jQuery library in my visual force page, but I've faced a major problem when I tried to use tabs "apex:tabPanel".

```
<script src="{!$Resource.jQuery}"></script> <!-- If I delete this script the tabs work !! -->

<apex:tabPanel tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab">
  <apex:tab label="Tab#1" id="tab1"></apex:tab>
  <apex:tab label="Tab#2" id="tab2"></apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
```

I get a "JS" errors in the console when I try to click on any tab, but if I delete jQuery library it works. So I guess there is a conflict between jQuery and apex:tabPanel functionality.